# Local Scope Resolution

Tags: c++, scope

I decided to change the scope of a function operator from global to local. After changing from the commented code, I found that my code no longer runs and exits with error:

> C4700 uninitialized local variable 'n' used.\

This seems to be a quite obvious contradiction to the actual method of local resolution. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

```
int Combs::factorial(int a)
{
    //value = 1;
    int n;
    for (int i = a; i >0; i--)
    {
        n *= i;
    }
    cout << n;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the variable is declared at global/file scope, the compiler initializes it for you, when it's local to a function, it doesn't, so you need to do it yourself.

`n` is indeed used unitialized, when it was a global variable it was not.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and I appreciate the help.

Comment: @ChrisHoy, glad to help, you can always [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) for a more substancial thanks ;)